# Removing unwanted row in a CSV file

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and I have a problem of removing unwanted rows in a csv file. For instance I have 3 columns and a lot of rows:

```
A      B     C
hi     1.0   5
hello  2.0   6
ok     3.0   7
```

I loaded the data using numpy (instead of csv)

```
import numpy as np
a= np.loadtxt('data.csv' , delimiter= ',' , skiprows= 1)
```

I want to introduce a range for the 2nd column

```
b=np.arange(0, 2.1,0.1)
```

I don't have any idea how I should use that piece of code.

What I want as a final output is the following:

```
A      B     C
hi     1.0   5
hello  2.0   6
```

The last row would be remove since I chose a range for the 2nd column up to 2.0 only. I don't have any idea how can I accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Try with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0) # column A will be the index.
a

       B  C
A          
hi     1  5
hello  2  6
ok     3  7
```

For every value of B up to 2 :

```
a[a.B <= 2]

       B  C
A          
hi     1  5
hello  2  6
```

---

Details :

```
a.B

A
hi       1
hello    2
ok       3
Name: B, dtype: float64

a.B <= 2

A
hi        True
hello     True
ok       False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I'll just put a[a.B <= 2]? What I mean is when I put "a.B", it will access the 2nd column?

Comment: yes, with Pandas you can access the columns with their name. So `a.B <= 2` will return a boolean array. (True if value in B is lewer or equal to 2, False otherwise). And `a[a.B <= 2]` will return values where the condition is satisfied

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using logical indexing

```
 index = (x[:, 1] <= 2.0)
```

Then

```
 x = x[index]
```

selecting only the lines that satisfy this condition

Comment: i got the following error: "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (997) into shape (1000)"

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the csv module. N.B the following expects that the CSV fields are comma separated, not tab separated (as your sample suggests).

```
import csv

with open('data.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)    # or csv.reader(data, delimiter='\t') for tabs
    field_names = next(reader)
    filtered_rows = [row for row in reader if 0 <= float(row[1]) <= 2.0]

>>> field_names
['A', 'B', 'C']
>>> filtered_rows
[['hi', '1.0', '5'], ['hello', '2.0', '6']]
>>> filtered_rows.insert(0, field_names)
>>> filtered_rows
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['hi', '1.0', '5'], ['hello', '2.0', '6']]
```

If you require that values be exact tenths within the required range, then you can do this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

allowed_values = np.arange(0, 2.1, 0.1)
with open('data.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    field_names = next(reader)
    filtered_rows = [row for row in reader if float(row[1]) in allowed_values]
```

**Edit after updated requirements**

With extra constraints on column "C", e.g. value must be >= 6.

```
import csv
import numpy as np

allowed_values_B = np.arange(0, 2.1, 0.1)
def accept_row(row):
    return (float(row[1]) in allowed_values_B) and (int(row[2]) >= 6)

with open('data.csv') as data:
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    field_names = next(reader)
    filtered_rows = [row for row in reader if accept_row(row)]

>>> filtered_rows
[['hello', '2.0', '6']]
```

Comment: Thank you! This one works but I will also present a different cut off for the 3rd column. Will this work?

filtered_rows2 = [row for row in reader if float(row[2]) in allowed_values]

Comment: @justin do you mean a completely separate view of the rows so that you have filtered_rows_B for column B (meeting one condition) and a separate filtered_rows_C (meeting a second condition)? ... Or do you mean just one filtered_rows meeting both conditions?

Comment: @mhwake: i want 1 filtered_rows where both conditions were met. :)